# How can i attach Calendar(Global) on click event of textbox?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internationalization

How can i attach Calendar(Global) on click event of textbox in dd-mm-yyyy format??
I am using Internationalization and want a user to select date in DD-MM-YYYY format as Date Of birth with specific culture.

With Specific culture i mean to display calendar in particular language like if CurrentCulture is China then calendar must look like [this but in parts](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=chinese%20calendar&hl=en&sa=X&biw=1366&bih=667&tbm=isch&prmd=imvns&tbnid=GhiQnkiU1KQXtM%3a&imgrefurl=http://withfriendship.com/user/kethan123/chinese-calendar.php&docid=c6Le-TQs0zlLTM&imgurl=http://withfriendship.com/images/c/12707/Chinese-calendar-pic.jpg&w=640&h=553&ei=uOwXT6zkMIHNrQfP0OjDDQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=176&vpy=324&dur=2232&hovh=209&hovw=242&tx=81&ty=106&sig=108143067603874562613&page=1&tbnh=132&tbnw=154&start=0&ndsp=21&ved=1t:429,r:7,s:0)

And if `CurrenCulture` is English then [Calendar is like](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=english%20calendar&hl=en&biw=1366&bih=667&tbm=isch&tbnid=gPlGbFgzuUIm5M%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.googlemodules.com/module/8930/&docid=V3e6lmYOG2WRiM&imgurl=http://www.googlemodules.com/image/screenshot/4AB6C779-0498-00B2-6B97-0B2EE81701A6.png&w=280&h=210&ei=nu4XT4ykIYTlrAeYns2rDA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=1101&vpy=199&dur=367&hovh=168&hovw=224&tx=134&ty=94&sig=108143067603874562613&page=1&tbnh=135&tbnw=192&start=0&ndsp=21&ved=1t:429,r:6,s:0)

**Updated**

In short i need Global datePicker Calendar on Textfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx) blog from ScottGu. It has explained how to do the culture in javascript using jQuery.

Hope this helps you.

Some other links

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/10/jquery-globalization-plugin.html

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx